# Error Message when saving Content

Tags: core

I have recently upgraded Civi to 5.4.0

When I want to save a content (Page, Webform, ...), I get the following error message :

Fatal error: Call to undefined function rules_action_drupal_goto() in /home/.../www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module on line 4021

Before upgrading Civi, I have already been using Drupal 7.59 for some months without having this problem.

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: This sounds something wrong with the Drupal Rules module. Did you try to upgrade the Drupal Rules module as well?

Comment: Thank you Jaap : you are right : it was due to a recent wrong movement in a Rule configuration. It is fixed now. If you move your comment to an answer, I will be happy to approve it.

Comment: I have created an answer from my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds something wrong with the Drupal Rules module. Did you try to upgrade the Drupal Rules module as well